# .click function is executed multiple times on every click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using an expandable card grid from CodePen (https://cdpn.io/nailaahmad/fullpage/LGRxWJ).
I added a button at the end of each card to close the current card and open the next one. It works well when you open the first card and click through all the card using that button at the end of each card. The cards can also be opened and closed by clicking on the card__inner element. When I mix the card__inner and the end of card navigation method, the function closeThisAndOpenNext is executed multiple times on every click of the  and not the adjacent card is opened, but one further away from the open card.

Does anyone know why and how to fix it so that only the card right next to the open card is opened with the "next"-button at the end of the card?

```js
var $cell = $('.card');
$('.js-next').hide();

//open and close card when clicked on card
$cell.find('.js-expander').click(function() {

  function getIndexOfList(list, element) {
    var $index = 0;
    for (let index = 0; index < $cell.length; index++) {
      const item = $cell[index];
      if (item == element[0]) {
        $index = index;
        break;
      }
    }
    return $index;
  }

  function closeThisAndOpenNext() {
    var $currentCard = $('.is-expanded')[0];
    $($currentCard).removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
    $($currentCard).find('.js-next:first').hide();

    //var $index = getIndexOfList($cell, $currentCard);
    $index = $($currentCard).data('index');

    if ($index < 9) {
      $nextCard = $cell[$index + 1];
    } else {
      return;
    }

    $($nextCard).removeClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-expanded');
    $($nextCard).find('.js-next:first').show();

    $nextButton = $($nextCard).find('.js-next:first');
    if ($nextButton.length > 0 && $nextButton[0].onclick == null) {
      $($nextButton).click(closeThisAndOpenNext);
    }
  }

  var $thisCell = null;
  if ($(this).find('.is-expanded').length == 0) {
    $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');
  } else {
    $thisCell = $(this).find('.is-expanded:first');
  }

  if ($thisCell.hasClass('is-collapsed')) {
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-inactive');
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-expanded');
    $($thisCell).find('.js-next:first').show();
    if ($cell.not($thisCell).hasClass('is-inactive')) {
      //do nothing
    } else {
      $cell.not($thisCell).addClass('is-inactive');
    }

    $nextButton = $thisCell.find('.js-next:first');
    $($nextButton).click(closeThisAndOpenNext);
  } else {
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');
    $($thisCell).find('.js-next:first').hide();
  }
});

//close card when click on cross
$cell.find('.js-collapser').click(function() {

  var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');

  $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
  $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');
  $($thisCell).find('.js-next:first').hide();
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eceef1;
  font-family: "Slabo 27px", serif;
  color: #333a45;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 5em auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.header {
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.header__title {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.header__subtitle {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #949fb0;
  font-family: "Yesteryear", cursive;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.cards {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card {
  margin: 15px;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 30px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 30px);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.card:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.card__inner {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #949fb0;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.card__inner:after {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card__inner .fa {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}

.card__expander {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #333a45;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.card__expander .fa {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card__expander .fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.card.is-collapsed .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
}

.card.is-collapsed .card__expander {
  max-height: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.card.is-expanded .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.card.is-expanded .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #333a45;
}

.card.is-expanded .card__inner .fa:before {
  content: "";
}

.card.is-expanded .card__expander {
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-top: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.card.is-expanded:hover .card__inner {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.card.is-inactive .card__inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.card.is-inactive:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #949fb0;
  transform: scale(1);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .card:nth-of-type(3n+2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3n+3) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-200% - 60px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3n+4) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .card__expander {
    width: calc(300% + 60px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card:nth-of-type(2n+2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(2n+3) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .card__expander {
    width: calc(200% + 30px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" href="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-5ae1a0698dcc2402e9712f7d01ed509a57814f994c660df9f7a952f3060705ee.png" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="CodePen">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-aec34940fbc1a6e787974dcd360f2c6b63348d4b1f4e06c77743096d55480f33.ico" />

  <link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-8f3771b1072e3c38bd662872f6b673a722f4b3ca2421637d5596661b4e2132cc.svg" color="#111" />


  <title>CodePen - Expanding Card Grid With Flexbox</title>


  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px|Yesteryear'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

  <script>
    window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
  </script>



  <script>
    if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
      window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
    }
  </script>


</head>

<body translate="no">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header">
      <h1 class="header__title">Expanding Card Grid</h1>
      <h2 class="header__subtitle">with Flexbox</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="cards">

      <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] " data-index="0">
        <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
          <span>Card</span>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card__expander">
          <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        </div>
        <div class="text-center js-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></div>
      </div>

      <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] " data-index="1">
        <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
          <span>Card</span>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card__expander">
          <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        </div>
        <div class="text-center js-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></div>
      </div>

      <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] " data-index="2">
        <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
          <span>Card</span>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card__expander">
          <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        </div>
        <div class="text-center js-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></div>
      </div>

      <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] " data-index="3">
        <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
          <span>Card</span>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card__expander">
          <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        </div>
        <div class="text-center js-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></div>
      </div>

      <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] " data-index="4">
        <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
          <span>Card</span>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card__expander">
          <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        </div>
        <div class="text-center js-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></div>
      </div>

      <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] " data-index="5">
        <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
          <span>Card</span>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card__expander">
          <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        </div>
        <div class="text-center js-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></div>
      </div>

      <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] " data-index="6">
        <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
          <span>Card</span>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card__expander">
          <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        </div>
        <div class="text-center js-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></div>
      </div>

      <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] " data-index="7">
        <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
          <span>Card</span>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card__expander">
          <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        </div>
        <div class="text-center js-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></div>
      </div>

      <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] " data-index="8">
        <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
          <span>Card</span>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card__expander">
          <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        </div>
        <div class="text-center js-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] " data-index="9">
        <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
          <span>Card</span>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card__expander">
          <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-1b93190375e9ccc259df3a57c1abc0e64599724ae30d7ea4c6877eb615f89387.js"></script>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve]

Comment: You have nested click handlers and weird functions inside functions. This is a mess. Clean it up first. You only need ONE click handler per element or if you delegate, per container

Comment: FYI in javascript, you don't need to prefix *all* your variables with `$` (var $index=0) - it just makes the code less readable (than it already was without simply clicking the tidy button, done for you).  *Some* people use `$` for jquery collections, but even then, there's no actual need.

Comment: As noted above: `function closeThisAndOpenNext() { ... nextButton.click(closeThisAndOpenNext); .. }` will add another click handler each time closeThisAndOpenNext is called, so will just keep increasing how far ahead it "jumps"

Comment: Quick fix, but better not to do this in the first place:  change `$($nextButton).click(closeThisAndOpenNext);` to `$nextButton.off("click"); $nextButton.click(closeThisAndOpenNext);`.  Better fix already detailed above (one click handler, never added again)

Comment: Also please chain and drop the `$($someJQueryObject)` like this: `$nextCard.removeClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-expanded').find('.js-next:first').show();`

Comment: @freedomn-m Likely you mean somehing like `$('.js-next').off('click'); $nextButton.on("click",closeThisAndOpenNext);` if jQuery supports off on a collection

Comment: @mplungjan probably, didn't look too closely at that mess of `$($($($var)))`.  If adding a click event, then turning off previous ones for that element should suffice.  Still better to do as you suggested up-front - single click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$($nextButton).click(closeThisAndOpenNext)` assigns an event handler. Every time this line runs, another event handler is assigned. Or at least this is my memory of how this is supposed to work. I haven't researched it for this answer.

But the idea is the same. Any time you see the same behavior on click happen many times instead of the one time you expect, you probably have multiple handlers of the same func assigned.

I suggest not having multiple functions inside of functions here, and make sure that things that you only want to happen once, at least check to see if it's already happened (been assigned) before doing it again.